# Referencing a DM channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a command that allows users to create their password following prompts through DM. I'm able to send a message to the user, but not able to read a message sent back with a `MessageCollector` because I cannot find a way to reference the DM channel.

I have tried using another instance of `bot.on("message", message)` here, but that creates a leak in the system causing the second instance to never disappear.

I also can't let users use a command say `!CreatePassword ***` because this function is linked with many others in a strict order.

Maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, or approaching the problem in a bad way, but I need a way to reference a DM channel.

This is the best iteration of my code so far.

```
function createAccount(receivedMessage, embedMessage)
{
    const chan = new Discord.DMChannel(bot, receivedMessage.author);

    const msgCollector = new Discord.MessageCollector(chan , m => m.author.id == receivedMessage.author.id);
    msgCollector.on("collect", (message) => 
    {
        // Other Code
        msgCollector.stop();
        // Removing an embed message on the server, which doesn't have a problem.
        embedMessage.delete();
    })
}
```

I can show the rest of my code if necessary.

Thank you for your time.  I've lost an entire night of sleep over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this (I'll assume that `receivedMessage` is the message that triggered the command, correct me if I'm wrong)

```
async function createAccount(receivedMessage, embedMessage) {
  // first send a message to the user, so that you're sure that the DM channel exists.
  let firstMsg = await receivedMessage.author.send("Type your password here");

  let filter = () => true; // you don't need it, since it's a DM.
  let collected = await firstMsg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
      maxMatches: 1, // you only need one message
      time: 60000 // the time you want it to run for
    }).catch(console.log);

  if (collected && collected.size > 0) {
    let password = collected.first().content.split(' ')[0]; // grab the password
    collected.forEach(msg => msg.delete()); // delete every collected message (and so the password)
    await firstMsg.edit("Password saved!"); // edit the first message you sent
  } else await firstMsg.edit("Command timed out :("); // no message has been received

  firstMsg.delete(30000); // delete it after 30 seconds
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct.
I didn't know about the `awaitMessages` function.  I tried dealing with it by creating a `DMChannel` or even `MssageCollector`.
But heck, you are big help, thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to hear that :) I always prefer using `.awaitMessages()` because you don't have to deal with events and you can use async/await